# Why is CakePHP 1.3 Pagination ignoring my order?

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I have a reports model, and I for the life of me cannot get it to change the order because of the use of the $this->paginate() in displaying the data. What am I doing wrong? It's as if the $paginate variable I set up has no impact whatsoever on the next line where $this->paginate() is called.

```
$this->Report->recursive = 0;
$paginate = array('order' => array('Report.id' => 'DESC'));
$this->set('reports', $this->paginate());
```

UPDATE:

I have tried a few more things, with no success at all.

1. I tried declaring the $paginate variable outside of the Report controller's index. This caused the page to not load
2. $paginate = array('order' => array('Report.id' => 'asc'),'limit' => 5);
3. $paginate = array('Report' => array('order' => array('Report.id' => 'asc'),'limit' => 5));
4. $paginate = array('order' => array('Report.id ASC'),'limit' => 5);
5. $paginate = array('order' => array('id' => 'asc'),'limit' => 5);

Neither the order, or the limit have any effect on the output of $this->paginate();

Comment: your initial setup looks good to me... Always worked for me this way! hm

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$this->paginate = array('Report' => array('order' => 'Report.id' => 'DESC'));
```

Replace your second line